# Simple full text search in ElasticSearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand how ElasticSearch Query DSL works.
It would be a lot of help if anyone could give me an example how to perform a search like the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE shop_id = 1 
AND MATCH(title, description) AGAINST ('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: May I know whether my answer was useful?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark it as correct. Worked fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you indexed some documents containing at least the shop_id, title and description fields, something like the following example:

```
{
    "shop_id" : "here goes your shop_id",
    "title" : "here goes your title",
    "description" : "here goes your description"
}
```

You can execute a [multi match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/multi-match-query/) against multiple fields, and give them a different weight (usually title is more important). You can also combine the query with a [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-filter/) on shop_id:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
        "query" : "here goes your query",
        "fields" : [ "title^2", "description" ]
    },
    "filter" : {
        "term" : { "shop_id" : "here goes your shop id" }
    }
}
```

You need to submit the query using the [search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/). Filters are used to reduce the set of documentsthe query is eecute against. Filters are faster since don't involve scoring and cached. In my example I applied a [top level filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter/), which might be or not a good fit for you depending on what else you want to do next. If you want to make a facet, for instance, the filter would be ignored in the facet. Another way to add a filter, which would be taken into account while computing the facets as well, is the [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/).

Comment: Can you please show me an example how to perform this kind of search but with a wildcard feature? I would like to match the title "Product" when I'm searching for "Prod".

Comment: Figured out that by following this guide: http://blog.avisi.nl/2012/02/22/searching-parts-of-words-with-elasticsearch/. Works great with javannas query DSL.